How to Mitigate Risks Before Delivering a Project with Limited Testing?
I’m currently leading a project where I completed 80% of the work myself because I felt a strong expectation from the team to ensure timely delivery. The rest of the team contributed about 20%. Due to complications with local testing, I skipped thorough local tests and relied primarily on integration and QA tests in the dev environment.
The QA tests so far seem to be going well. However, I still have doubts about potential bugs and whether the QA tests cover all critical scenarios.
Our tech lead suggested postponing the delivery to allow more testing and review, but I opposed this, insisting I would take responsibility and lead the delivery. Despite my confidence, I’m now questioning whether we’ve done enough to mitigate risks before moving to production.
What are the best steps to ensure stability and minimize risks at this stage, given the limited testing? How can I better handle similar situations in the future to balance delivery speed with quality assurance?

Tests aren't just written for one release. They also help to stop the codebase turning into legacy code.
If the test coverage is insufficient, it will be difficult for future maintainers of the code.
I would recommend you agree a minimum engineering standard with your team and do not ship the code until that standard is achieved.

If you have to consider postponing a release then I wonder if the release is already too big. Releases ought to be as small and frequent as possible so that the risk and impact is minimized - at least daily for example.
The fact that you have described this as "delivering a project" sounds ominously like a big bang style of release. Those are extremely hard to get right and imply a lot of work and dissatisfaction on all sides. Certainly you can expect to follow it up with many more releases to fix defects. If you are already committed to it then one option may be to release as soon as possible, fail fast and get the pain over with.

If you have concerns, you should be able to define what they are. A general feeling of unease shouldn't normally be enough to delay a project - everyone has these doubts - but if there are areas that you can point to that are giving you specific concerns, these are the areas to concentrate on.
I suggest trying to document your concerns in a form along the lines of "There is a risk that (something goes wrong) due to (a reason such as lack of testing), leading to (a negative outcome that can be specified)". For example: "There is a risk that users can enter invalid numbers of products to be ordered due to lack of input value validation, leading to these values being written into the database that will generate incorrect orders that need to be rectified".
Then you can put a likelihood and an impact against all of the individual risks (in my example, perhaps a medium likelihood and a high impact), allowing you to focus your attention on the worst scenarios and in conjunction with the business, make a decision based on whether they are so bad that the business wouldn't accept the risk, or whether the risks are acceptable. In either case, you should discuss the risks with the business that will have to live with them, to determine whether the risks need to be mitigated before the system goes live, or whether you can mitigate them after go-live - or even live with them forever!
Whatever you come up with, make sure you involve your users in any final decisions as to how to proceed. They may accept the risks, they may mitigate the risks in some way, or they may ask that you delay the implementation to allow for extra testing. It should be their decision, not yours, as to how to proceed.


What are the best steps to ensure stability and minimize risks at this stage, given the limited testing? How can I better handle similar situations in the future to balance delivery speed with quality assurance?

You tagged your question as "agile." Agility is a set of values and principles, and isn't simply a set of fixed practices. Collaboration and communication are two of agility's foundational operating principles.
Agility is generally iterative. Agile delivery is about delivering something that's "good enough" to generate validated learning and practical feedback post-delivery. Since your current iteration is almost over it's too late to go back and address first principles this time around. Near term, focus on setting expectations about what will be delivered, what won't be, and then gathering actionable feedback about the delivered increment. You should then fold all the feedback and lessons learned into your next agile increment.
To improve for the future, address the foundational principles and practices that may not have been optimal this time. Specifically, you should improve the following:

Focus on collective ownership and broader collaboration. Agile frameworks are ineffective when people don't trust each other to deliver value together, or when one person has to (or chooses to) play the lone hero. You need to fix that dynamic within your group.
You need a definition of done. Scope can be flexible, but if you can't be sure whether something meets your quality goals or shared objectives then what you're doing isn't really "agile." Agility isn't about doing "all the things on time," it's about delivering increments of value that meet your working agreements. It has nothing to do with guarantees about fitness for purpose or being bug-free, but frequently includes things like routine test coverage and regression testing.
Work on building better TDD practices, and take a test-first approach to building the product. Agility is about delivering valuable increments within a time box, not meeting arbitrary deadlines at any cost. If scope is not flexible, then schedule, budget, or quality have to flex instead. A good test-first approach ensures that quality and testing aren't afterthoughts, and that even if you miss a product goal that the product still remains in a potentially-releasable state at all times.
Have a common iteration goal and shared understanding of how to meet that goal. You currently have at least two people that disagree on some project basics. You didn't actually agree on the goal, how you could work together to meet that goal, or even if the intended goal was reasonable. As a result, you currently lack the ability to reset expectations about your current iteration, an increment that meets a shared understanding of quality, or a properly-executed definition of done. When you take solo ownership, then you generally take solo responsibility as well. Work towards better collaboration instead.
You took on too much, over-promised, and now feel that you may under-deliver. Next time, focus on continuous communication rather than faster delivery. The time to discuss challenges with delivering an increment of wokr is not at the end of an iteration. Instead, work should be decomposed so that problems can be identified as early as possible so that they can be addressed as a team, or necessary changes to scope or schedule can be effectively communicated to stakeholders earlier to properly align everyone's expectations.

Basically, this time around you should just deliver what you can and learn from the experience. You may even discover that what you've got is "good enough," even if you still have room for more process or product improvements in the future.
After that, focus on ensuring that you don't repeat the same mistakes, anti-patterns, or even just sub-optimal application of agile principles next time. Don't focus on blame; it sounds like there's plenty to go around. However, take responsibility for any mistakes you made and lack of team cohesion you contributed towards, and then commit to doing less of those things in future.
